# How to use CakePHP validation without having to define model validation rules?

Tags: validation, cakephp

I have a contact form that doesn't use a model. What's the best way to validate its data?

Should I use <del>cake's automagic goodness and have it create a dummy model on the fly</del> a pre-defined dummy model that validates the data according to the rules I add on the fly or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, it has always been that you create a model for situations like these, and then set:

```
var $useTable = false;
```

in the model. You don't have to do it "on-the-fly". It's just a model with validation rules, without an associated table.

Here's a [link](http://snook.ca/archives/cakephp/contact_form_cakephp) that should help you with this.

Comment: And I always thought that it's quicker and better to skip the model and use some hacky validation inside the controller action. Really, what was I thinking? Thanks a lot for making this a lot more clearer to me! :)